# Android Backup and Restore

Tags: backup, restore

I have rooted android phone. I backed up a application, uninstalled the application from the phone and restored it back the way it was there in the phone(using backup including changes to packages.list and packages.xml). The restored application is not showing up immediately but shows up after reboot of the phone.

Is there any service that has to be restarted to recognize the presence of the app immediately?

Comment: Which phone do you have?  You might have to kill/restart the launcher in order to see new apps in the app drawer.

Comment: Oh, great! I've posted that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 4):

If it'll help, an app like [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (sounds like you're probably already rooted) handles pretty much everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to kill/restart the launcher in order to see new apps in the app drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You want Titanium Backup.  Just backup the user apps and not the system.

[Titanium Backup in Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&feature=search_result)